# Extract certain substring in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence, which is:

```
User update personal account ID from P150567 to A250356.
```

I want to extract the keywords "`P10567`" from this sentence.

How do I extract data between the sentence using regex or string method?

Comment: Hint: get a substring from index of "from" to index of "to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- String method:

  Use `StringUtils.substringBetween()` of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/):

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String sentence = "User update personal account ID from P150567 to A250356.";
      String id = StringUtils.substringBetween(sentence, "from ", " to");
      System.out.println(id);
  }
  ```
- Regex method:

  Use regex `from (.*) to`, the string  surrounded by parentheses  is
  called `group(1)`, just extract it:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String regex = "from (.*) to";
      String sentence = "User update personal account ID from P150567 to A250356.";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
      matcher.find();
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
  ```