# How to get the middle strings with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string that looks like this

DatalogSetupFile: BTS50xx1EJA\3.20\log_all.stp

The `DatalogSetupFile:` and `\3.20\log_all.stp` are constant. I wish to extract `BTS50xx1EJA` from the string. How should I do it?

Comment: [`DatalogSetupFile:\s(.*)\\3.20\\log_all\.stp`](https://regex101.com/r/SNA0s4/1) ?

Comment: This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Or `string.substring(18, string.length()-17)`

Comment: See this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227485/extract-keywords-from-string-in-java/49227906#49227906

Comment: @chrisz thank you it works! I tried (?<=DatalogSetupFile: )(.*)(?=\\log_all\.stp) but is not working. I am grateful =)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a regex group in which you can specify what all are the static content and then specify what are the dynamic content as a whole group, So that you can get the dynamic content as a whole group,

You can define regex as follow

^(?:DatalogSetupFile:\s)**(.*)**(?:\3.20\log_all.stp)$

Try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/as8hVi/1)

Here you can use the first group to get your dynamic string

Comment: Post a _complete_ answer, not just a link to an off-site resource.   Don’t get me wrong: the offsite links are useful and valuable; but by themselves, they aren’t an answer.  You almost started to explain use of groups in regex ... but stopped far short of trying.

Comment: Why do you need a non capture group for the last part of the string?

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, with all of the relevant content here. Links should only be used as additional reference material. A link to an off-site answer (*see this link*) are not acceptable here.

Comment: I used non capture group regex because he need only specific string only

Comment: You don’t have a non-capturing group at the end!  You have a capturing group that starts (optionally) with a colon!   `(?:  )` verses `(:?  )`.  And there is little point to using non-capturing groups; the stuff outside of a group (capturing or not) is not captured.

Answer (score 0):

Give this regex a try:

```
\s\K[^\\]+
```

Which, in Java would look like:

```
String myInputString = "DatalogSetupFile: BTS50xx1EJA\\3.20\\log_all.stp";
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\K[^\\\\]+");
Matcher myMatcher = Pattern.matcher(myInputString);
System.out.println(myMatcher.group(0));
```

Comment: Your code `.compile("\s\K...` doesn’t have enough backslashes in it.